# Root права на iOS

Tags: ios, apple

Зачем Root права и почему на iPhone нет возможности их получить? Для чего они нужны?

Comment: рут права в IOS как и в Android позволяют углубленно кастомировать прошивку, взламывать офлайн игры и много чего еще, получить можно, но там очень много проблем с этим и самое главное сперва нужно решить а нужны ли рут права. так как они несут потенциальную угрозу если не умеешь пользоваться рутом

Comment: Если вы спросили это на стаке, то с большой долей вероятности вы получите кирпич уже на 2-3 день использования JB. JB - привередливый и требует внимания. Хоть он и предназначен для простых смертных - ошибок он терпеть не станет.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы купили устройство на базе iOS в кредит, то смело делайте Jailbreak т.к. на всё самое лучшее из AppStore у вас просто не хватит денег. Именно этим соображением руководствуются 99% людей делающие Jailbreak. К ним же можно отнести людей купивших устройство привязанное к оператору по скидке (контракту) и желающих отвязать от последнего. Оставшийся 1% использует Jailbreak для кастомизации телефона (сменить функционал и внешний вид Springboard, кастомизировать стандартные приложения, прокачать стандартную звонилку или выключить ненужные демоны). Если вы не попадаете в эти 2 категории, то не используйте средства получения Root прав в iOS. С точки зрения программиста, я больше чем уверен, что будь вы таковым, то не задавались бы подобным вопросом на SO.

Поскольку iOS закрытая операционная система не позволяющая кастомизировать внешний вид и функционал Springboard (он же GUI), то по большей части это было одной из нескольких причин создания Jailbreak. Второй была, отвязка устройства от оператора (собственно название говорит само за себя). Может быть и наоборот, не помню. А уж после подтянулись халявщики с магазином ломанных программ из AppStore типа Installous.

В Android OS в качестве GUI используется Launcher, который можно изменить установив отдельно другой как программу из Play Market и установив в качестве лаунчера по умолчанию. Что позволит без каких-либо проблем изменить внешний вид меню и функционал до неузнаваемости. Поэтому Root права на Android используют больше для патчинга и твиков.

Надеюсь я полностью раскрыл истинный смысл вашего вопроса.